# TFTP server not working

Tags: server, tftp, xinetd

I'm trying to set up a TFTP server using xinetd but I haven't had any luck so far.
I have installed the following packages: xinetd, tftpd, tftp.

After that I changed the `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` so that it would start the tftp automaticaly and even restarted the machine to see if it would work (yes, I'm that desperate...). It doesn't seem to get it working.

Then I tryed using the tftp command to get a file from another pc. Here is the thing, I can get something from another tftp server, but not from my localhost. The other machine can't fetch anything from mine either.

Oh, and I did a `chmod 777` to both `/tftpboot` and the `foo` file I'm using in this test.

Anyone knows why am I the only being that can't use the tftp as it should?
Just a last minute update, when I type "status" inside the tftp command I get this:

```
tftp> status
Not connected.
Mode: netascii Verbose: off Tracing: off
Rexmt-interval: 5 seconds, Max-timeout: 25 seconds
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I solved this problem installing the atftpd package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP [reported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237287/tftp-server-not-working#comment295530_237287) that installing the [atftpd [image: Install atftpd]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/atftpd) package solved this problem.